# Definition of ブラコン when discussing musical preferences

Tags: meaning, definitions, slang, music

A Japanese person told me that they have ブラコン。I looked it up on Wikipedia and it said something like an emotional attachment to one's brother. But they said that it meant something like someone who likes rap music. I couldn't find a definition like this. Is this what it means?

Comment: Which Wikipedia did you check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R&B, not rap. Straight from [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3&oldid=15934234) ("black contemporary").

Comment: Is there any more to it? Is it racial?

Comment: "Black music" is a common name in Japan for R&B and similar... It is obviously racial and probably would be offensive in any other country, but people are fine with it in Japan.

Comment: It might not refer to exactly the same genres, but I have found a similar term on the English Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_music